# Multiple File upload Command line script in Moodle 2

Tags: php, file-upload, command-line-interface, moodle

I got command line script for file upload to courses in moodle the coding is as follows.

Add multiple resources to a course (to first section of a course). Resources will be named “Files A”, “File B” and so on. To every resource, we will upload multiple files and will decide which file goes where depending on the file name, eg. files starting with “a” will go to a resource named “Files A”.

What i did step by step:

- Get file resource context ID
- Get file storage (singleton)
- Create file info data
- Upload file

And now, while getting a resource context ID, we’ll have to make sure we will choose the right resource name (eg. “Files A”) and that this resource does exist. So, we’ll need a function that will do that for us and create all needed resources.

Then we’ll need to make sure that newly created resources are visible, are available, have created context, resources are placed in a correct course section and so on. We could also check if module is enabled and many other things, but it’ll be good enough for this example.

And after whole operation, we’ll clean course cache so users could see new course elements.

```
<?php
define('CLI_SCRIPT', true);

// this is config.php within Moodle installation
require_once('config.php');

$courseid = $argv[1];
$filename = $argv[2];

$course_name = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid), 'id, shortname')
        or die("Course not found");

$course_destination['path'] = "/files/"; // any path that starts and ends with "/"
$course_destination['filename'] = $filename;
$course_destination['resource_name'] = 'Files ' . get_first_letter(clean_string($filename));

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    upload_for_course($uploadcourseid, $path, $course_destination);
} else {
    echo "Not uploading, file does not exist\n";
}

function upload_for_course($courseid, $source_filename, $destination) {
    global $DB, $CFG;

    if (file_exists($source_filename) && is_readable($source_filename)) {

        require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/lib/filestorage/file_storage.php');

        $sql = "SELECT m.id moduleid, cm.id cmid, cm.course courseid, cm.module moduleid
            FROM {course_modules} cm, {modules} m
            WHERE m.id = cm.module AND cm.course=$courseid AND m.name='resource'";

        $resource = get_resource($courseid, $destination['resource_name']);

        $fs = get_file_storage();

        // Prepare file record object
        $fileinfo = array(
            'contextid' => $resource->id, // ID of context
            'component' => 'mod_resource',     // usually = table name
            'filearea' => 'content',     // usually = table name
            'itemid' => 0,               // usually = ID of row in table
            'filepath' => $destination['path'],           // any path beginning and ending in /
            'filename' => $destination['filename']); // any filename


        $fs->create_file_from_pathname($fileinfo, $source_filename);


    } else {
        die("Error: Not exist or not readable: " . $source_filename . "\n");
    }

}

function clean_string($str) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');

    $chars = "\\/`!@#$%^&*()_-=+|}{]['\";:?><,. \t\n";

    $str = strtolower( trim( strip_tags($str), $chars) );
    $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $str);

    return $str;
}

function get_first_letter($str) {
    $str = clean_string($str);

    // return first letter
    return strtoupper(substr($str, 0, 1));
}

function get_resource($courseid, $resource_name) {
    global $DB, $CFG;
    $sql = "SELECT cm.id as cmid FROM {course_modules} cm, {resource} res
        WHERE res.name = '" . $resource_name . "'
        AND cm.course = " . $courseid . "
        AND cm.instance = res.id";


    if (! $coursemodule = $DB->get_record_sql($sql)) {

        $letters = range('A', 'Z');

        require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/course/lib.php');

        echo "\tCreate new resouces\n";

        foreach($letters as $key => $letter) {

            $course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid), '*', MUST_EXIST);
            // get module id
            $module = $DB->get_record('modules', array('name' => 'resource'), '*', MUST_EXIST);
            // get course section
            $cw = get_course_section(0, $course->id);
            $sectionid = $DB->get_record('course_sections', array('course' => $this->courseid, 'section' => $cw->id), '*', MUST_EXIST);

            $resource_data = new stdClass();
            $resource_data->course = $course->id;
            $resource_data->name = 'Files ' . strtoupper($letter);
            $resource_data->intro = '<p>'.'Files ' . strtoupper($letter).'</p>';
            $resource_data->introformat = 1;
            $resource_data->tobemigrated = 0;
            $resource_data->legacyfiles = 0;
            $resource_data->display = 0;
            $resource_data->displayoptions = 'a:2:{s:12:"printheading";i:0;s:10:"printintro";i:1;}';
            $resource_data->revision = 1;
            $resource_data->completion = 1;
            $resource_data->showavailability = 1;
            $resource_data->timemodified = time();

            $resource_id = $DB->insert_record('resource', $resource_data);

            // add course module
            $cm = new stdClass();
            $cm->course = $courseid;
            $cm->module = $module->id; // should be retrieved from mdl_modules
            $cm->instance = $resource_id; // from mdl_resource
            $cm->section = $sectionid->id; // from mdl_course_sections
            $cm->visible = 1;
            $cm->visibleold = 1;
            $cm->showavailability = 1;
            $cm->added = time();

            $cmid = $DB->insert_record('course_modules', $cm);

            // add module to course section so it'll be visible
            if ($DB->record_exists('course_sections', array('course' => $courseid, 'section' => 1))) {
                $sectionid = $DB->get_record('course_sections', array('course' => $courseid, 'section' => 1));

                // if sequence is not empty, add another course_module id
                if (!empty($sectionid->sequence)) {
                    $sequence = $sectionid->sequence . ',' . $cmid;
                } else {
                    // if sequence is empty, add course_module id
                    $sequence = $cmid;
                }

                $course_section = new stdClass();
                $course_section->id = $sectionid->id;
                $course_section->course = $courseid;
                $course_section->section = 1;
                $course_section->sequence = $sequence;
                $csid = $DB->update_record('course_sections', $course_section);

            } else {
                $sequence = $cmid;

                $course_section = new stdClass();
                $course_section->course = $courseid;
                $course_section->section = 1;
                $course_section->sequence = $sequence;

                $csid = $DB->insert_record('course_sections', $course_section);

            }

            // force clear module cache
            $modulecache = new stdClass();
            $modulecache->id = $courseid;
            $modulecache->sectioncache = 'NULL';
            $DB->update_record('course', $modulecache);

        } // foreach

        // get context again, this time with all resources present
        $context = get_resource($courseid, $resource_name);
        return $context;

    } else {

        $context = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_MODULE, $coursemodule->cmid);

        return $context;
    }


} // get_resource
}
```

input is like

```
/> php filename.php courseid "upload/file/path" 

example: 

/> php script.php 4 "E:\file\untitled-1.pdf"
```

but the result is error

```
Error: Not exists or Not readable
```

Please help to solve this issue.
    Can it be fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a thought but have you looked at using the file repository? You can FTP files into a folder in the moodle data directory - then attach a link to the file - its useful if the file is updated for any reason - http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/File_system_repository

Comment: Russell, I tried FTP earlier i can FTP files to folder with course ids. But i only see the documents but have to manually upload the files to the particular course. To make them upload to courses. For that only i did this script. Suggest any thoughts on this. Thanks

Comment: Yeah have a look through the instructions at the link I gave you. First you need to create the folders in the moodledata directory, then set up the folder as a repository in Moodle, then you add the files to a course - if you have a look at the resource code to see how it links a file from the repository to the course.

Comment: Russell, I use 2.4.2 where. I used file repository to store files and made them to available in course. But I cant make them link to the particular courses. So i tried this script.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code because the version of moodle I've tried it told me that some features were deprecated.

I have tested the code below and could create a folder with files or a resource with file.

First for resources I made this:

```
function get_resource($courseid, $resource_name) {
    global $DB, $CFG;

    $sql = "SELECT cm.id as cmid FROM {course_modules} cm, {resource} res
        WHERE res.name = '" . $resource_name . "'
        AND cm.course = " . $courseid . "
        AND cm.instance = res.id";

    if (! $coursemodule = $DB->get_record_sql($sql)) {      
        require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/course/lib.php');

        echo "\tCreate new resouce\n";

        $course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid), '*', MUST_EXIST);

        // get module id
        $module = $DB->get_record('modules', array('name' => 'resource'), '*', MUST_EXIST);

        // get course section
        course_create_sections_if_missing($course->id, 0);
        $modinfo = get_fast_modinfo($course->id);
        $cw = $modinfo->get_section_info(0);

        echo "section id: " . $cw->id;

        $sectionid = $DB->get_record('course_sections', array('course' => $course->id, 'name' => 'Recursos'), '*', MUST_EXIST);         

        $resource_data = new stdClass();
        $resource_data->course = $course->id;
        $resource_data->name = $resource_name;
        $resource_data->intro = '<p>'.$resource_name.'</p>';
        $resource_data->introformat = 1;
        $resource_data->tobemigrated = 0;
        $resource_data->legacyfiles = 0;
        $resource_data->display = 0;
        $resource_data->displayoptions = 'a:2:{s:12:"printheading";i:0;s:10:"printintro";i:1;}';
        $resource_data->revision = 1;
        $resource_data->completion = 1;
        $resource_data->showavailability = 1;
        $resource_data->timemodified = time();

        $resource_id = $DB->insert_record('resource', $resource_data);

        // add course module
        $cm = new stdClass();
        $cm->course = $courseid;
        $cm->module = $module->id; // should be retrieved from mdl_modules
        $cm->instance = $resource_id; // from mdl_resource
        $cm->section = $sectionid->id; // from mdl_course_sections
        $cm->visible = 1;
        $cm->visibleold = 1;
        $cm->showavailability = 1;
        $cm->added = time();

        $cmid = $DB->insert_record('course_modules', $cm);

        // add module to course section so it'll be visible
        if ($DB->record_exists('course_sections', array('course' => $courseid, 'section' => 1))) {
            $sectionid = $DB->get_record('course_sections', array('course' => $courseid, 'section' => 1));

            // if sequence is not empty, add another course_module id
            if (!empty($sectionid->sequence)) {
                $sequence = $sectionid->sequence . ',' . $cmid;
            } else {
                // if sequence is empty, add course_module id
                $sequence = $cmid;
            }

            $course_section = new stdClass();
            $course_section->id = $sectionid->id;
            $course_section->course = $courseid;
            $course_section->section = 1;
            $course_section->sequence = $sequence;
            $csid = $DB->update_record('course_sections', $course_section);

        } else {

            $sequence = $cmid;

            $course_section = new stdClass();
            $course_section->course = $courseid;
            $course_section->section = 1;
            $course_section->sequence = $sequence;

            $csid = $DB->insert_record('course_sections', $course_section);
        }

        rebuild_course_cache($courseid, true);      

        // get context again, this time with all resources present
        $context = get_resource($courseid, $resource_name);
        return $context;

    } else {
        $context = context_module::instance($coursemodule->cmid); 

        return $context;
    }
} // get_resource
```

And for folders I made this:

```
function get_folder($courseid, $resource_name) {
    global $DB, $CFG;

    $sql = "SELECT cm.id as cmid FROM {course_modules} cm, {folder} res
        WHERE res.name = '" . $resource_name . "'
        AND cm.course = " . $courseid . "
        AND cm.instance = res.id";

    if (! $coursemodule = $DB->get_record_sql($sql)) {      
        require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/course/lib.php');

        echo "\tCreate new folder\n";

        $course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid), '*', MUST_EXIST);

        // get module id
        $module = $DB->get_record('modules', array('name' => 'folder'), '*', MUST_EXIST);

        // get course section
        course_create_sections_if_missing($course->id, 0);
        $modinfo = get_fast_modinfo($course->id);
        $cw = $modinfo->get_section_info(0);

        echo "section id: " . $cw->id;

        $sectionid = $DB->get_record('course_sections', array('course' => $course->id, 'name' => 'Recursos'), '*', MUST_EXIST);

        $folder_data = new stdClass();
        $folder_data->course = $course->id;
        $folder_data->name = $resource_name;            
        $folder_data->intro = '<p>'.$resource_name.'</p>';
        $folder_data->introformat = 1;
        $folder_data->revision = 1;
        $folder_data->timemodified = time();
        $folder_data->display = 0;
        $folder_data->showexpanded = 1;
        $folder_data->showdownloadfolder = 1;

        $folder_id = $DB->insert_record('folder', $folder_data);

        echo "folder id: " . $folder_id;

        // add course module
        $cm = new stdClass();
        $cm->course = $courseid;
        $cm->module = $module->id; // should be retrieved from mdl_modules
        $cm->instance = $folder_id; // from mdl_resource
        $cm->section = $sectionid->id; // from mdl_course_sections
        $cm->visible = 1;
        $cm->visibleold = 1;
        $cm->showavailability = 1;
        $cm->added = time();

        $cmid = $DB->insert_record('course_modules', $cm);

        // add module to course section so it'll be visible
        if ($DB->record_exists('course_sections', array('course' => $courseid, 'section' => 1))) {
            $sectionid = $DB->get_record('course_sections', array('course' => $courseid, 'section' => 1));

            // if sequence is not empty, add another course_module id
            if (!empty($sectionid->sequence)) {
                $sequence = $sectionid->sequence . ',' . $cmid;
            } else {
                // if sequence is empty, add course_module id
                $sequence = $cmid;
            }

            $course_section = new stdClass();
            $course_section->id = $sectionid->id;
            $course_section->course = $courseid;
            $course_section->section = 1;
            $course_section->sequence = $sequence;
            $csid = $DB->update_record('course_sections', $course_section);

        } else {

            $sequence = $cmid;

            $course_section = new stdClass();
            $course_section->course = $courseid;
            $course_section->section = 1;
            $course_section->sequence = $sequence;

            $csid = $DB->insert_record('course_sections', $course_section);
        }

        rebuild_course_cache($courseid, true);      

        // get context again, this time with all resources present
        $context = get_folder($courseid, $resource_name);
        return $context;

    } else {
        $context = context_module::instance($coursemodule->cmid); 

        return $context;
    }
} // get_folder
```

And how I call this functions:

```
$resource = get_folder($course, 'Folder Script'); // for folders
//$resource = get_resource($course, 'Resource Script'); // for resources

$fs = get_file_storage();
$filename = 'Text1.txt';    

// Prepare file record object
$fileinfo = array(
      'contextid' => $resource->id, // ID of context
      'component' => 'mod_folder',     // usually = table name
      'filearea' => 'content',     // usually = table name
      'itemid' => 0,               // usually = ID of row in table
      'filepath' => '/',           // any path beginning and ending in /
      'filename' => $filename); // any filename
/*$fileinfo = array(
      'contextid' => $resource->id, // ID of context
      'component' => 'mod_resource',     // usually = table name
      'filearea' => 'content',     // usually = table name
      'itemid' => 0,               // usually = ID of row in table
      'filepath' => '/',           // any path beginning and ending in /
      'filename' => $filename); // any filename
*/

$path_upload = '/path/Text1.txt';   

$existingfile = $fs->file_exists($resource->id, 'mod_resource', 'content', 0, '/', $filename);

if ($existingfile) {
    //the file exists
} else {
    $fs->create_file_from_pathname($fileinfo, $path_upload);
    //file uploaded
}
```

Note that this is a quick test.

I hope this will serve you.